# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.metric.sql.SqlViewMetricExporterSpi

Tags: java, ignite

Trying out an apache ignite example and ran into below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.metric.sql.SqlViewMetricExporterSpi
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.newInstance(IgniteUtils.java:1737)
    ... 10 more
```

Here is the code snippet to start my ignite

```
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);

        IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.cache("baeldungCache");

        cache.put(1, "baeldung cache value");

        String message = cache.get(1);
        System.out.println("Ignite started and executed.");
```

Below is my pom

```
 <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
            <ignite.version>2.13.0</ignite.version>
            <h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>
   </properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring-data</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I think I have added all the required jars.

What's missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ignite-indexing to your list of dependencies.

For more information on integrating Apache Ignite with Spring-Data see [docs](https://You%20need%20to%20add%20ignite-indexing%20to%20your%20dependency%20list).